# How to read from multithreading log4j2 buffer

Tags: java, multithreading, junit4, log4j2, maven-surefire-plugin

I have executed automated test cases with multithreads, managed by `maven-surefire-plugin`. Each class has their own thread where it is executing and the **log4j2** is configured with `bufferIO = true` and `immediateFlush= true`. In the output file, all the threads are mixing the information. I know that **log4j2** has this buffer and I would like to know if each thread has their own buffer and if I can read from it before the information is written into the output file.

I read other [question related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51474636/junit5-mixed-logs-with-parallel-execution) to this topic, but it hasn't arrived at a solution. And for that reason, I'm trying to search another path to follow.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to read from internal logging buffers?

Comment: Because the output log is mixed. I would like obtain the log of each thread separate

Comment: To obtain each test case output to review the errors more clearly

Comment: Just use tools to filter files by thread name or test case or whatever. Why overcomplicate matters? If you want to use an over engineered approach, just use a filtering appender to dump different logs into different files

Comment: I appreciate your comments and if you have a solution for this topic I propose you put an answer with filter in log4j2 or with grep if you know it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you want to run assertions against the log output, you are probably better off by not using a file appender, but configure a special in-memory appender that collects everything in a way that is convenient for your test case to inspect. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827677/how-to-do-a-junit-assert-on-a-message-in-a-logger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I found is that `JUnit5` is the cause of the mixed output log file, when we execute the test cases in multithreading way. When I used `JUnit4` the default output, usually the console waits for the end of the test case to write.

In other hand the output file from `log4j`, when the user execute it with multithreding, always it shows mixing all the threads, regardless of the JUnit version.

Them, I add the thread id to the log4j layout pattern:
`%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p- **[%tid]** %m%n`

And after finish each thread I read the last lines of the output log4j file and I filter by the thread id number to obtain the relevant lines. With this point I had to solve other problem. How to obtain the absolute path of a dynamic log4j output log file? I test two solutions:

1. By reflection (not recommended, but faster)
2. Implement your own FileAppender to create a method to access to the `fileName` field

The two steps to follow the first option are this:

```
LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Appender appender = ctx.getConfiguration().getAppenders().get("file");
```

The `appender`variable has the fileName field, but it is private.